# Collatz's hypothesis testing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to build a small program to test the collatz's hypothesis. So far, I have the following:

```
c0 = int(input("Enter an integer and non-zero number"))
steps = 0
while c0 != 1:
    if c0%2:
        c0 = c0/2
        steps += 1
    elif c0%2 !=0: 
        c0= (3*c0) + 1
        steps += 1
    print (c0)
print (steps)
```

But when I run it, it's going into an endless loop of 0.0s. Not really getting where the problem is.

Comment: `if c0 % 2` gets executed if `c0 % 2` returns 1. So does `elif c0%2 != 0`. Your elif clause will never get executed.

Comment: `c0%2` means the number is odd. If you want to check if it's even, use `c0%2==0`

Comment: Also you probably want to use `//` instead of `/`, otherwise your data type will change to float.

Comment: Was about to write the same as @khelwood. If you divide with `/`, the return value is a float. You never want to compare floats with `==`. (just look at the return value of `2.3 %2`). If you use `//`, you're dividing integers. The result will be like `/` rounded down to the next lower integer, but since you're only dividing even numbers, this won't matter. And your `==0` comparison is guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot people.I got it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Nearoo mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64496875/collatzs-hypothesis-testing-in-python#comment114045091_64496875), `c0 % 2` is the same as `c0 % 2 != 0` because `1` (when c0 is odd, 'c0 % 2' is 1) has a boolean value of True.

Here's the correct solution:

```py
n = int(input("Enter a strictly positive integer: "))
steps = 0
while n != 1:
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = n / 2
    elif n % 2 == 1: 
        n = (3*n) + 1
    steps += 1
    print(int(n))

print (steps)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also give you the desired result, though the steps are long but will help you understand the flow.

```
c0 = int(input('Enter a non- negative, non-zero integer: '))
step = 0
while c0 != 1:
    if c0 % 2 == 0:
        c0 //= 2
        if c0 != 1:
            step += 1
            print(' New value is ', c0)
            continue
        elif c0 == 1:
            step += 1
            print(' New value is ', c0)
            break
    elif c0 % 2 == 1:
        c0 = c0 * 3 + 1
        if c0 != 1:
            step += 1
            print(' New value is ', c0)
            continue

print('Total Steps: ', step)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).